# Product to extend the navigation portlet? (aka override the plone_control_panel nav settings)

Tags: plone

I need to have two navigation portlets  (in plone4):

- one "classic" (with the settings defined in the plone_control_panel / navigation)
- another one with types defined in the navtree portlet instanced

Advices?

Vito

Answer (score 1):

Some tips and ideas.

Copy-paste the existing navigation portlet code to a new portlet.

Then you need to adjust its "navigation tree strategy" so that it collects only content types you define

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/misc/navigationtree.html#creating-a-custom-navigation-tree

How to create a z3c.form vocabulary to pick out content types:

http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functionality/controlpanel.html#content-type-choice-setting